# MyScript Interactive Ink SDK conversion to math returns?

Tags: swift, xcode, handwriting-recognition

I am using the MyScript Interactive ink SDK to convert handwritten math equations. I tested out the SDK using the test examples they have and everything worked great. I imported a lot of their code logic to my application and am successfully able to set up the engine and the editor. I can write items and even use the redo, clear and undo items in the editor. The problem is that every time I attempt to covert it, it returns a "?".

The function to convert is below and is exactly the same as the code in the example that MyScript provides -

```
@IBAction func ConvertButtonWasTouchedUpInside(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    do {
        editorViewController.editor.waitForIdle()
        let supportedTargetStates = editorViewController.editor.getSupportedTargetConversionState(nil)
        try editorViewController.editor.convert(nil, targetState: supportedTargetStates[0].value)
    } catch {
        print("Error while converting : " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    do
    {
        try equationInLatex = editorViewController.editor.export_(nil, mimeType: .laTeX)

    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error while printing : " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    print(equationInLatex)
}
```

The code to create the package for the engine and the code to setup in engine in the file AppDelegate.swift is also the same.

I have attached an image on what the return value looks

**like here**

[image]

I am not able to figure out why I am experiencing this error and what part of the engine and/or editor set-up I am doing incorrectly.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing the recognition assets.

In the provided GetStartedSwift example there is a `recognition-assets` folder that is referenced in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase, as shown in the snapshot. You must copy those files to your project as well.

[image: recognition assets]

You can rename the recognition-assets folder if you wish, but if you do so you'll have to change the `"configuration-manager.search-path"` setting in AppDelegate.swift

If you only want math recognition you may want to copy only math related files: `conf/math.conf`, `resources/math/math-ak.res`, and `resources/math/math-grm-atk.res`